# Was upgrading from 16.04 to 18.04 and suddenly system got hanged and then shut down. After that ain't able to run it

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, 18.04

I was upgrading from 16.04 to 18.04 and suddenly my system hanged and then shut down in the middle of the update. I was doing some other work meanwhile so wasn't able to see whether it completed or not.(possibly it wasn't. As while typing sudo apt-get update - in one of the linea it was showing that 920 files are partially broken or removed)

And now while logging, its taking me to lockscreen and when I'm entering my password, I'm getting to the same place again and again.

I tried going to grub menu and then opening *advanced options for Ubuntu* and going for the recovery mode.
After that clicking the following in the same order ( as someone suggested the same which I read somewhere)
1. Grub
2. Network
3. Root
4. Dpkg

And then doing the normal boot. But the issue still remains.

I'm new here so doesn't knows much. Is there anyone who can help me out with the same.